# How to select all points of a polygon in Spatialite

Tags: sql, geometry, spatialite, sqlite, geometry-conversion

I need to select all vertex coordinates from a polygon table in Spatialite DB. In PostGIS, I'd normally do something like

```
SELECT 
  st_x((st_dumppoints(poly_geom)).geom),
  st_y((st_dumppoints(poly_geom)).geom)
FROM
  my_poly_table;
```

But there is no `st_dumppoints` function in Spatialite. 
How can I get a table with every vertex of every feature?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_DissolvePoints(geometry))), 
ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_DissolvePoints(geometry))) 
FROM my_poly_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a two-phase process that must utilize ST_DissolvePoints https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html and ElementaryGeometries
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/info/d6069e7bf8c7f124

Virtual table ElementaryGeometries was introduced in SpatiaLite 4.2.1 but I had to use version 4.4.0-RC0 for getting the results.

First, create a new table 'multipoints' that stores the polygon geometries as multipoints. Here is an example with one in-line polygon:

```
CREATE TABLE multipoints AS 
SELECT  ST_DissolvePoints
(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 340 520, 340 540, 360 540, 360 520, 340 520 ))'))
AS geometry;
```

Now you can query the ElementaryGeometries virtual table:

```
SELECT mp.rowid, e.item_no, ST_AsText(e.geometry) AS geometry
FROM multipoints AS mp
JOIN ElementaryGeometries AS e ON (e.f_table_name = 'multipoints' 
AND e.origin_rowid = mp.rowid);


1   0   POINT(340 520)
1   1   POINT(340 540)
1   2   POINT(360 540)
1   3   POINT(360 520)
1   4   POINT(340 520)
```