# Best method for expanding Multi* geometries to their constituent objects

Tags: postgis, geopandas, shapely, spatialite, geoalchemy-2

I have a SpatiaLite table with a geometry column containing a mix of multi and single geometries, e.g. (Multipolygon, Polygon) or (MultiLineString, LineString). The application that will be reading this data unfortunately does not handle Multi* geometries well so I'll need to expand them using `ST_Dump` or something similar.

I assume it's better to move the resultant rows to a new table, correct me if that's not the optimal way. I want to make sure the new table has a unique primary key for each row (expanded and non-expanded geoms). There are other columns in the table besides the geometry column so I would like those to be duplicated for each Multi geometry that gets expanded. e.g.

**Original table**

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------+
| object_id |     city      | state |              geom              |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------+
|         1 | Dallas        | TX    | MultiPolygon(((<coords>)))     |
|         2 | Los Angeles   | CA    | Polygon((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0)) |
|         3 | New York City | NY    | Polygon((3 0,5 1,4 2,1 0,2 1)) |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------+
```

**Expanded table (Lets say the MultiPolygon is made up of 4 polygons)**

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------+
| object_id |     city      | state |              geom              |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------+
|         1 | Dallas        | TX    | Polygon((8 4,1 1,1 1,3 0,2 0)) |
|         2 | Dallas        | TX    | Polygon((1 6,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0)) |
|         3 | Dallas        | TX    | Polygon((1 1,1 1,2 1,1 0,1 0)) |
|         4 | Dallas        | TX    | Polygon((1 3,1 7,1 1,1 9,1 0)) |
|         5 | Los Angeles   | CA    | Polygon((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0)) |
|         6 | New York City | NY    | Polygon((3 0,5 1,4 2,1 0,2 1)) |
+-----------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------+
```

Could this be done and can I generate my own primary key? In this case the PK would be `object_id`.

I have a few methods in mind:

1. Use GeoPandas to manipulate the columns and add the new rows.

   - Extract the inner geoms (Shapely `multipolygon.geoms`)
   - Append the extracted `geoms` as new rows
   - Drop the current `object_id` column
   - Add a new `object_id` column
   - Write the GeoDataFrame back to SpatiaLite
2. Just use SQL(via GeoAlchemy) to perform the above steps from (1). I would imagine `row_num()` would be used to generate the new primary key column. Would this be too complex/not possible?

A concern with option (1) is the amount of memory that might be used if the table is massive since GeoPandas loads everything into memory.

Which of these options might be better, or is there another way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpatiaLite has a function "ElemantaryGeometries" just for this purpose. The usage is documented in http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.0.html

```
Will create a new out_table directly corresponding to in_table.
The output table will be arranged in such a way that each row will 
always contain an elementary Geometry; so each time that a MULTI-type
Geometry is found in the input table it will be split into many
distinct rows.

    out_pk is the name to be set for the output Primary Key, and
    out_multi_id is the name to be set for a second column within the
    output table where to store the a zero-based index from which
    Geometry the Element-Geometry comes from, that together with the
    original Primary Key can be identified.
    Note: both out_pk and out_multi_id must not exist in the given
    in_table table.
The optional argument transaction determines if an internal SQL
Transaction should be automatically started or not (the default
setting if not explicitly overridden is TRUE).

Optional arguments: a maximum of 10 further options could be
eventually be specified. Valid options are:

    ::ignore::column_name
    Note: the geom-column will never be ignored, even if explicitly
    requested to be.
    ::cast2multi::
    Will automatically apply a CastToMulti ( geom_column ) directive.
    All references to mismatching options or not existing columns will
    be silently discarded.
```

Comment: Thanks! Didnt know this function existed. So I guess the geometries that weren't originally Multi* would have a null value for the `out_multi_id`. I probably wont need the optional parameters but for my understanding, how would I pass in the `::ignore::` optional argument? Would it be called option_1 or ignore? And positionally, is `ignore` before `cast2multi`? Thanks.

Comment: SpatiaLite 5.0 RC1 appeared today into the repository and I have not tested the new options. The version 4.3.0 http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html (link will point to newer version in the future) does not have those extra options. This answer may also be useful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228308/how-to-select-all-points-of-a-polygon-in-spatialite as well as this SpatiaLite document https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/info/d6069e7bf8c7f124